# How is website cloning search results from other site?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

Ok so here is the case: Site A is a directory website for plumbers where you can search for plumbers by entering your zip code. Once you hit search then all the plumbers in your area shown in list ( just like yelp).

Site B is a totally different site but it essentially works the same way. The thing that gets me is that this site is mirroring the results from site A exactly aside from css. All information is the same so I am wondering how they are able to do this? After research I found both websites are owned by same company and they accomplished this by creating a plugin for site B to mirror these results. But what would this consist of, process etc?

Comment: same company -- probably the same code then. How does site X do Y is off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't see how it is off topic if I am trying to learn how to do this so I can implement it myself. I am sure it is not the same code because as I said it is pulling the data from the 1st domain.

Comment: well then ask that ^^^ question. Not how X does Y. But " I want to do ... i have tried ... the results wher ..."

Comment: a million domains can share the same code BTW. we run a few hundred with multiple shared libraries

Comment: I am sure you are right about them sharing some code but I doubt they are sharing the whole library because it seems it is more of a light version. I am trying to accomplish the same thing on 2 of my websites. I guess I am just trying to find out whats the best way to do this without having to copy the whole code over.

Comment: dont copy it over, just use it on both sites

Comment: I'm a rookie and barely starting php, didn't know this was possible. Can you guide me in the right direction, like article or something of that nature?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the site in a programming framework by creating sections in a partials folder, then yielding that content on two separate layout files. Apply different stylesheets to the layout files. That's half the story and the rest depends on what exactly you want to implement as this can either be one project with styles dependent on the URL rewriting, the one layout file mirrored as an index on another site, or separate projects with either the exact same or replicated databases. Laravel and Meteor are examples of such frameworks.